# Module not found in App.js when deploying

Tags: next.js

does anyone have any clue why im getting this error when deploying and how i can fix it?

./pages/_app.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '../components' in '/vercel/path0/pages'

```
import React from "react";
import { Toaster } from "react-hot-toast";

import { Layout } from "../components";
import "../styles/globals.css";
import { StateContext } from "../context/StateContext";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <StateContext>
      <Layout>
        <Toaster />
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Layout>
    </StateContext>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

This is the code for the layout part of component

```
import React from "react";
import Head from "next/head";
import Navbar from "./Navbar";
import Footer from "./Footer";

const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <div className="layout">
      <Head>
        <title>My Store Front</title>
      </Head>
      <header>
        <Navbar />
      </header>
      <main className="main-container">{children}</main>
      <footer>
        <Footer />
      </footer>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Layout;
```

Index.js (barrel folder)

```
export { default as Footer } from "./Footer";
export { default as Layout } from "./Layout";
export { default as Navbar } from "./Navbar";
export { default as Product } from "./Product";
export { default as HeroBanner } from "./HeroBanner";
export { default as FooterBanner } from "./FooterBanner";
export { default as Cart } from "./Cart";
```

Comment: Are you using a barrel file in the `components` folder to export all your components?

Comment: What happens when you do that ? import { Layout } from "../components/Layout.js";

Comment: @juliomalves yes!

Comment: Also getting these errors similar errors                                                                         Failed to compile.
./pages/_app.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '../components' in '/vercel/path0/pages'
./pages/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '../components' in '/vercel/path0/pages'
./pages/product/[slug].js
Module not found: Can't resolve '../../components' in '/vercel/path0/pages/product'
> Build failed because of webpack errors
Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1